# Quake 3 doesn't install in Windows 7

Tags: technical-issues, windows-7, quake-3

I have a Dell Studio laptop with Intel Core 2 Duo 2.8 GHz processor, 4 GB Ram, 512 MB ATI Raedon Graphics Card and 500 GB HDD with Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit. I was checking my shelf for old games and came across Quake 3 Arena. Though its more than a decade old now, I'm still a big fan.

I tried installing this game by double-clicking the setup.exe file but nothing happens. I can see that the process is listed in the processes tab of task manager but in vain. I don't see anything happening.

Assuming that this could be because I'm installing an old game on a 64-bit machine, I tried to change the compatibility to Windows XP Service Pack 3/Service Pack 2. Nothing seems to help.

Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Comment: Have you tried right clicking the setup file and selecting "Run as Administrator?"

Comment: Wasn't the game source code released openly a while ago? Might want to check the net, see if anyone's got a working project.

Comment: @Krazer: Yes, I tried that. Didn't help.

Comment: Have you tried running the setup file in compatibility mode? http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/316-compatibility-mode.html

Comment: Yes, I tried that too. Tried setting the compatibility mode to win xp SP2 and SP3.

Answer (score 2):

I did some quick googling, and the [ioquake3](http://ioquake3.org/get-it/) project seems to have a working client you can use with ID's own data files.